# Looking for "Camera Mouse" for Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, camera

I have come across a cool piece of software called [Camera Mouse](http://cameramouse.org/index.html). It lets you control your mouse cursor with just a webcam. Is there software like that for Linux based operating systems? (I would prefer something from the Debian repository, but compiling from source is cool too)

Comment: Have you tried running it under WINE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [MouseTrap](http://live.gnome.org/MouseTrap) from the GNOME project. Debian package name: `gnome-mousetrap`. Because of [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=655930) it is at the moment unfortunately only usable in Debian stable.

And there is also [eViaCam](http://eviacam.sourceforge.net/), but it is not yet included in Debian (but there is a [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cesar-crea-si/+archive/eviacam)). It seems to be more mature than MouseTrap.